# From where to get data of the received/measured Moon temperatures of the last 50 years?

Tags: the-moon, temperature

Are there any accessible public data or charts of the measured and received **Moon temperatures over the years**?

What is the long term reliability of the instruments installed by the landings? If the (redundant) sensors were made of semiconductors, they may have suffered from cosmic rays/particles, since a heavy lead shield would have been probably too heavy.
And more and more dust would influence the values, perhaps some moonquakes would decrease the thickness of a dust layer?

Is there any site with a comprehensive technical description and data for downloading?

Answer (score 8):

The Apollo missions took ALSEPs to the Moon that ran for years and provided surface and subsurface temperatures at specific spots along with other data. [See this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26503/12102) to get an idea what the data looked like. They also used the ALSEP radio signals for lunar ranging experiments but they eventually stopped:  [Why were the "perfectly functioning" seismometers placed by Apollo 12, 14, 15 and 16 astronauts all shut off in 1977?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26502/12102)

The Earth's atmosphere has an infrared window so I suppose lunar temperatures could be roughly estimated by thermal IR spectroscopy with a small telescope, but it wouldn't be extremely accurate. Thermal imaging of the Moon from orbit may have been done, but I don't think there will be a continuous record of temperature at even one spot, much less the whole surface that is decades long and unbroken. *That's just my guess.* There will also be thermal IR measurements from lunar orbit but those only measure a patch at a time; there isn't continuous coverage either.

See for example [The global surface temperatures of the Moon as measured by the Diviner Lunar Radiometer Experiment](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103516304869) which is onboard the [Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Reconnaissance_Orbiter) (LRO). See UCLA's web page [LRO DIVINER Lunar Radiometer Experiment](http://diviner.ucla.edu)

You can click on "data" to get instructions how to understand the size and contents of the data archive. There is quite a lot there to see!

2.8 MB "cool" GIF too large to embed with imgur:
[https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e870e6_4cc302bfb6254bf39a15c4e7ab6850b2~mv2.gif](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e870e6_4cc302bfb6254bf39a15c4e7ab6850b2%7Emv2.gif)

One frame from that GIF reminds us that each spot on the Moon spends a half-month roasty-toasty in the Sun and the other exposed to the c-c-c-cold of space.

Any given spot on the Moon cycles through "warm" to very cold each month, it will be difficult to spot a small change in temperature due to shifting regolith, but may be possible with extremely careful observations. I don't know if the LRO data are good enough for that or not, but it is possible!

[image: one frame of GIF from LRO DIVINER Lunar Radiometer Experiment http://diviner.ucla.edu]

[image: UCLA New Diviner Seasonal Polar Data Products Maximum summer and winter temperatures for the south polar region to 80°S]

> Figure: Maximum summer and winter temperatures for the south polar region to 80°S latitude derived from polar data products with 110 K contoured with a black line (From Williams et al., JGR, 2019).

#### I didn't realize the Moon *had seasons!*